# Does the htaccess file change any other files on update?

Tags: .htaccess

I added 3 lines of code to the htaccess folder to remove the file extension on the directory, that broke many links, I reverted it back to the default file and the same errors are happening. I don't have the lines but I just need to know if there is anything else this folder changes after the changes take effect.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add those 3 lines of `.htaccess` code. Without the details, we won't be able to provide solid solutions to your problem. Also, see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you've removed the lines then it's not doing anything. However, depending on what code you had in the first place, you may be seeing a cached response. "the htaccess folder" - htaccess is not a "folder", it's a file called `.htaccess` (dot prefix).

Answer (score 0):

[@MrWhite's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70873668/does-the-htaccess-file-change-any-other-files-on-update/70884672#comment125299218_70873668) was correct: It ended up being just cached data saved in Chrome. I just had to clear the cache on Chrome to solve the issue.